# React does not recognize my file to connect to firebase. What is the solution?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

My application gives an error to connect to Firebase. What is the solution of this? I couldn't find out what the configuration error was.

> Failed to compile
>   ./src/config/fbconfig.jsx
>     Line 17:  'config' is not defined  no-undef
>   Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {reduxFirestore,getFirestore} from 'redux-firestore'
import {reactReduxFirebase,getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase'
import fbConfig from './config/fbconfig';


const store=createStore(rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase,getFirestore})),
        reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
    ));


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

fbconfig.jsx

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';


var Config = {
    apiKey: "************************",
    authDomain: "omega-yazilim.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://omega-yazilim.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "omega-yazilim",
    storageBucket: "omega-yazilim.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "562730339151",
    appId: "1:562730339151:web:b5b71c922561259823933a",
    measurementId: "G-KVFKV8PLQW"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  firebase.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots:true});

  export default firebase;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "omaga-yazilim",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^npm i --save react-router4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.8.1",
    "jest-leak-detector": "^25.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.4.0-beta.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.12.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You've named the variable `Config` with an uppercase `C`, but are passing it into Firebase as `config` with a lowercase `c`. Make the casing match and the error will disappear

Comment: I match but I get an error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase / app' in 'C: \ Users \ 2020 \ reactapp \ src \ config'